# Adding hyperlinks from database to query results

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, url, href

New to this kind of thing.

Essentially I just want the returned url value (see below) to display itself as a hyperlink. "url" is the name of a column in the database that contains (obviously) a website url.

Previously I would have used something like this:

```
echo "<a href=".$row['url'].">".$row['url']."</a>";
```

But I'm not sure of the syntax in this context. Here is a snippet of the code:

```
 function createMarker(latlng, venuename, url, address, phone) {
      var html = "<b>" + venuename + 
      "</b> <br/>" + url +
      "</b> <br/>" + address + 
      "</b> <br/>" + phone;
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: latlng
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
      markers.push(marker);
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean how do you pass an array in php so it calls this javascript function for each result AND makes the url a link? If so try something like this:

in your footer, in a window.load function or whatever way you choose to serve js after page loads:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php foreach($db_array AS $row): ?>
    createMarker('<?php echo $row['latlng']; ?>', '<?php echo $row['venuename']; ?>', '<?php echo $row['url']; ?>', '<?php echo $row['address']; ?>', '<?php echo $row['phone']; ?>');
<?php endforeach; ?>

function createMarker(latlng, venuename, url, address, phone) {
          var html = "<b>" + venuename + 
          "</b> <br/><a href=\"" + url + "\">" + url + "</a>" +
          "</b> <br/>" + address + 
          "</b> <br/>" + phone;
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: latlng
          });
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(html);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
          });
          markers.push(marker);
        }
</script>
```

This assumes you have a database result array called $db_array and the fields match the same names as the js function. Obviously you replace these values with your actual ones.

Answer (score 0):

The first one of them is a simple php echoed link and the later one is javascript for creating google marker. you will want to decide what you want to do. Is it simply a link? or create a marker?

And you have some html element does not match up in the javascript.

For this particular output, you may add this before the function:

```
var url = <?php echo $row['url']; ?>
```

But of course I don't know how you want to loop it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's a marker, on a map, that contains the venue name, address, phone number, and (ideally) a weblink, which is derived from $row['url']. Just out of curiosity, do you know what the syntax would be for adding even a generic hyperlink to any of the text generated inside the createMarker function?